# Ruby calculator - hash not storing correctly

Tags: ruby, hash, calculator

So I'll start off by writing that I am new to this site (today), as well as to the Ruby programming language (3 days ago), so don't feel afraid to rip apart my code--I am trying to learn and get better.

Basically.. I am creating a console calculator that is able to read a simple math problem (or string of math problems) from the user and solve the equation. It doesn't use order of operations or anything fancy (yet) and it is basically working except for this one weird bug I can't figure out.

```
Userinput = "1 + 2 + 3 - 4"
# First I split the user input into an array of stirngs and then loop over the
# array of strings and depict whether a string is a key or hash (see code below)

# program should store these characters in a hash like so.. 
hash = { nil=>1, "+"=>2, "+"=>3, "-"=>4 }
```

Then I would use the key of the hash to determine whether or not I was adding, subtracting, multiplying, or dividing next.

Everything pretty much works fine! Its just that when I do a problem with more than 2 operations (i.e. 1 + 2 - 0 + 3) the program will just randomly leave out some keys and operators. I have been trying different examples to search for a pattern but I cant find the source. Below I'll post examples of the problem and their output, as well as the hash itself, and then full source code. Thanks in advance for any help or critiques!

***Examples format***

Program Input (user prompt, user input) --
Program output (sum of equation) --
hash at the end of execution

Example 1

> Type a math problem (ex. 40 / 5): 40 / 5 + 2 - 5 * 5 - 5 * 5 - 100
>
> -450
>
> {nil=>40, "/"=>5, "+"=>2, "-"=>100, "*"=>5}

Example 2

> Type a math problem (ex. 40 / 5): 1 + 2 - 0 + 3
>
> 4
>
> {nil=>1, "+"=>3, "-"=>0}

Example 3

> Type a math problem (ex. 40 / 5): 10 - 5 * 2 + 8 + 2
>
> 12
>
> {nil=>10, "-"=>5, "*"=>2, "+"=>2}

Source code: main.rb

```
=begin
  
  main.rb
  Version 1.0
  Written by Alex Hail - 10/16/2016
 
  Parses a basic, user-entered arithmetic equation and solves it
 
=end

@operationsParser = ""    # global parser
@lastKeyAdded = ""

private
def appointType(sv)
    if sv =~ /\d/
      sv.to_i
    else
      sv
    end
end

private
def operate(operations)
  sum = 0
  operations.each do |k, v|
    if k.nil?
      sum += v
    else
      case k
        when '+' then sum += v
        when '-' then sum -= v
        when '*' then sum = sum * v  
        when '/' then sum = sum / v
        else
      end
     end
   end
   sum
 end

private
def solveEquation
  print "Type a math problem (ex. 40 / 5): "
  userInput = gets.chomp
  
  #array to hold all numbers and their cooresponding operation
  operations = {}   # <== Empty hash
  
  #split the user input via spaces
  @operationsParser = userInput.split(" ")
  
  #convert numbers into numbers store operators in hash ( nil => 40, "/" => 5) -- would be 40 / 5
  @operationsParser.each do |stringValue|
    if appointType(stringValue).is_a? Integer
      

     operations[@lastKeyAdded != "" ? @lastKeyAdded : nil] = appointType(stringValue)
        
    else #appointType will return a string by default
      keyToAdd = appointType(stringValue)
      @lastKeyAdded = keyToAdd
    end
  end
  
  #check if operators(+, *, -, /, or nil) in the keys are valid, if not, error and exit, if so, operate
  operations.each do |k,v|
    case k
      when '+'
      when '-'
      when '*'    
      when '/'
      when nil
      else
        # Exit the program if we have an invalid operator in the hash
        puts "Exiting program with error - Invalid operator used (Only +, -, *, / please)"
        return
    end
  end
  
  sum = operate(operations)
  
  
  puts sum, operations
end

solveEquation
```

Comment: You can't have `{ "+" => 1, "+" => 2 }`, it's impossible. Remember, hashes are limited to one instance per key, so if a token appears twice this will break down. What about an Array?

Comment: Ohhh you are very right! Silly me.. I could probably just use an array and parse it that way. Thanks!!

Comment: You could convert your sequence to [Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) in an Array, for example: `2+3*4-1` becomes `['-', ['+', 2, ['*', 3, 4]], 1]`.

Comment: tadman took the words right out of my mouth this was a java homework back in undergrad. Alex were you looking for a parsing answer as well?

Comment: I'll look into Polish notation after work tonight. I'll be updating this calculator for quite awhile so I'll have plenty of time to refactor. Thanks all!

Comment: I suggest that in future you hold off making a selection for awhile, lest you discourage other answers or short-circuit others who are still working on answers. Many here wait at least a couple of hours before awarding the greenie (some wait much longer). This is not a reflection on the answer you selected (which I've not read).

Comment: Ahhh okay. I'll keep this in mind next time Cary. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so the problem is the data structure that you chose, a hash by definition has to always maintain a set of unique keys to map to its values. Now something you could try if you are dead set on using a hash is mapping all the keys to empty arrays then add numerical values to that then process that operation on every value in it respective array(since you are ignoring order of operations any way)

```
h = Hash.new([]) #to set the default value of each key to an empty arrary
```

then when you process your array it should look like this

```
{nil =>[1], '+' => [1, 2, 3], '-' => [3, 7], '*' => [4, 47], '/' => [3, 5]}
```

Comment: Someone answered my question in the comments on my original post but this was very helpful as well so I'll put this one as the accepted answer to let people know my problem was solved.

Comment: Ok good luck to you in your pursuit of knowledge this is a good excise.